# Good alternatives to onion routing (for anonymously sending messages and/or files over the internet)?

Tags: networking, routes, anonymous, tor

I'm currently looking for some good techniques to anonymously send and receive messages and/or files over the internet.
Currently I'm only really familiar with tor which is based on Onion routing.

I found another technique called AntsP2P (http://antsp2p.altervista.org/) which is based on Antnet (http://people.idsia.ch/~gianni/antnet.html).
I can't really figure out how that technique provides anonimity though.

Anyway.. Are there some good alternatives to onion routing when it comes to anonymously sending messages and/or files over the internet?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tox is an opensource software that you can use to anonymously send messages.
It works very simply, when you lanch it for the first time, you get a public key that you can send to anyone you want to chat with. The other do the same and you get a crypted connection to send messages and files !

link : [Tox](https://tox.chat/)

Comment: Cool! Thnx, I'll definitely look into it!